# How to know when and how many SPAlerts were sent?

Tags: alert

I would like to know when and how many SPAlerts are sent to a specific user, is there any way to do this?

Comment: You need to clarify as one alert can send many emails - so are you asking how many emails all alerts have been sent to a user or how many alerts a user is signed up to?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is probably just inspect your mail server logs.

The alerts are just fired out by timerjobs, not sure if it logs how many & to whom they were sent.

Answer (score 1):

here is the code to achieve it:

```
SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
SPWebCollection collWebsites = oSite.AllWebs;
foreach (SPWeb oWebsite in collWebsites)
{

    SPAlertCollection collAlerts = oWebsite.users["LoginName"].Alerts;    
    foreach (SPAlert oAlert in collAlerts)
    {
        //do something
    }
    oWebsite.Dispose();
}
```